# Issue with getting web3.eth.accounts (MetaMask)

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

My MetaMask is enabled, but in console I see empty array [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z9kG.png), also when I tried `console.log(web3.eth.accounts[0])`, it returns `undefined`.

But when I'm using `console.log(web3.eth)`, I see in console all the data [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRp81.png)

Does anybody know why `web3.eth.accounts[0]` or `web3.eth.accounts` doesn't work?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function(){
                if( typeof web3 !='undefined'){
                    console.log('web3 detected');
                    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);                                    
                    console.log(web3.eth.accounts);
                }else{
                    alert("please install MetaMask");
                }
            });
                       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved problem, using:

```
 web3.eth.getAccounts((err, res) => {                   
                   console.log(res[0]);
});
```

but I don't know why `web3.eth.accounts[0]` doesn't work

Comment: It doesn't work because it's not a list of accounts as you expected. It's a constructor for a whole package you can use. Check [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

For getting currently connected accounts you need to write,

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
web3.eth.requestAccounts().then(accounts => console.log(accounts));
```

Answer (score 0):

`web3.eth.accounts[0]` does not work because `web3.eth.accounts` is not a list a of accounts, as it says in the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth-accounts.html#web3-eth-accounts):

[image]

Get the accounts like so:

```
var account = null;
web3.eth.getAccounts(async function(error, accounts) {
  if (error == null && accounts.length > 0) {
      account = accounts[0];
   }
}
```